# Changing iCloud id to email: The requested application was not found on this server

Tags: icloud

I am trying out iCloud right now but it keeps telling me:

```
An Apple ID that is an email address is required to use iCloud.
```

I am using a non email username(that I use for itunes and the app store) so I followed the link to convert it but going to https://appleid.apple.com redirects me to:

https://appleid.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MyAppleId.woa/

and gives me the above error. So what should I do now?

Comment: Reload the page. The servers are overloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reload the page. The servers are overloaded (this question was posted on the iCloud launch day).